# How to replace factor NA's with the level of the cell above

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace NA values in factor column with the values of the cell above. It would be great to have this in a tidy verse approach, but it doesn't matter too much if its not.
I have data that looks like:

```
data <- tibble(site = as.factor(c("A", "A", NA, "B","B", NA,"C", NA, "C")),
               value = c(1, 2, NA, 1, 2, NA, 1, NA, 2))
```

And I need it to look like:

```
output <- data <- tibble(site = as.factor(c("A", "A", "A", "B","B", "B","C", "C", "C")),
                         value = c(1, 1, NA, 1,2, NA, 1, NA, 2))
```

I've tried a few different approaches using `lag` and `replace_na` although they have basically amounted to trying the same thing which is:

```
mutate(site = as.character(site),
    site = ifelse(is.na(site), "zero", site),
    site = ifelse(site == "zero", lag(site), site),
    site = as.factor(site))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Using `zoo` package, you could do `mutate(data, site = na.locf(site))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `fill()` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
data <- data %>% fill(site)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  site  value
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A         1
2 A         2
3 A        NA
4 B         1
5 B         2
6 B        NA
7 C         1
8 C        NA
9 C         2
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
data$state <- na.locf0(data$site)
```